# Silverlight and DataGridColumn type

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid with DataGridTemplateColumn and DataGridTextColumn in it.
In my backend code I'm looping thru the datagrid.Columns Collections to see if the column has a binding or not.
I need to know How can I determine if the Columns type is of DataGridBoundColumn or NOT??
Any ideas which method/property does that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn col in this.Columns)
```

{
  if (col is DataGridBoundColumn)
   {
     DataGridBoundColumn = column = col as DataGridBoundColumn;
   }
}